# How to set a click limit to a button in java?

Tags: java, swing

In the program i am making, whenever i click a button, a counter counts the clicks the user makes to a certain button and subtracts them to a number given.I want to make a limit when the button is pressed certain times, the program stops subtracting from the given number. How can i make this limit?
this is the code from one of the buttons i am making (the other do excactly the same)

```
int clicks;
private void v1OcActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     

    int j=clicks++;
    tOc.setCountWater(tOc.getCountWater()-1);
    System.out.println(tOc.getCountWater());
    if(j==7){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The valve is below 25%, the valve will close.");
    }

}
```

Comment: ... `if (clicks < limit) { (do action) };`?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is the answer you are looking for, but I 100% guarantee this is a duplicate of another question and next time you should thoroughly search for the answer first before posting a question.

```
   int clicks;
    private void v1OcActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {  

        clicks++;

        if(clicks >= 7){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The valve is below 25%, the valve will close.");
        } else {
            tOc.setCountWater(tOc.getCountWater()-1);
        }
        System.out.println(tOc.getCountWater());
    }
```

Comment: If you want to stop recording clicks when you reach your limit put `clicks++;` in the else statement.